# move to the target URL after PHP CURL form submit

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I'm new to this. I have just discovered curl.
Looks like I'm missing something.

Here's the idea.

1. HTML page has a form with one hidden field that POSTs it to a php file (order.php) after a user clicks SUBMIT.
2. order.php then generates a bunch of other parameters and POSTs them to a different php file (ordercheck.php)
3. ordercheck.php uses the POSTed data.

This almost works.

BUT: the problem is that the browser still shows order.php in the address field.

Is there a way for the browser to move to ordercheck.php after order.php has POSTed?

Eventually, I would like to move from order.php to a different server (paypal's webscr), so simply processing the data is not good enough for me. I need to actually post the data AND move to the new url, as if it were a normal form submission...

PLEASE help!

Answer (score 2):

yes  simply add a redirect after the curl request like so

```
header("Location: newPage.php");
```

Id probably do a check to make sure the curl request was successful then add the header within the php code which will redirect the user.

if your curl request is initialised with a variable like $ch then just do somethign like:

```
if ($ch){
   header("Location: newPage.php");
}
```

This wil make sure the curl request reutrned true and completed.

Comment: Thank you. But for some reason it gives me Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by order.php. The error is displayed AFTER the output from ordercheck.php (which basically echos values from $_POST)

Comment: Im having a think about how you can do this.  If you need a real quick fix even though not the ideal way you could just put a meta refresh tag on the page you want to move away form.  like this: http://www.pageresource.com/html/metref.htm   however Im gonna see if I can think of a slicker way

Comment: Thinking about it you may be getting the headers already sent message due ot one of the options being set or not being set see this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER is the one in particular Im thinking of.  The reason I say this is I know one of the curl ootions returns the page which means the headers are already set but by xchanging the option the headers are not set and the redirect I expalined above acan take place.

Comment: notto complicate things further but you do have other tools around that will do the same thing as CUrl like Jquery.  With Jquery you can do simplar things  look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: could it be that php treats the output sent by ordercheck.php but displayed on order.php as headers sent by order.php.